# How do I copy photos from an iMessage chat to the iOS Camera Roll?

Tags: ios, photos, messages, copy-paste

When I long press on a photo someone shared with me in an iMessage chat I get three main options: Copy, More..., and Speak. More only presents options to delete all, or select some messages to forward to someone. Speak doesn't seem useful. So can I copy a photo into my camera roll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Tap on the photo bubble in the message list.
2. Tap to bring up the photo controls.
3. Press the **Share** button, and select **Save Image**.

   [image]

<sup>This works in both iOS 6 and iOS 7.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

1. Tap the photo to open it
2. Press the `Share` button and select `Save Image`

Answer (score 0):

Press on photo in text message and 'save' appears. Hit save and it goes straight to photo collection

Answer (score -1):

Copy picture, paste in an email and send it to yourself, then save.

Comment: Hi and welcome. This may be an option. But this answer does not address the specific  question. Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer which will give you a better insight into how to answer questions here that will be considered useful.